# wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com' inside alpine docker image

Tags: docker, dns, alpine-linux

```
/ # wget -O - https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v${HUGO_VERSION}/${HUGO_ID}
_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
--2021-02-09 08:03:32--  https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.76.5/hugo_extended_0.76.5_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Name does not resolve.
```

Inside alpine, I was unable to resolve github.com. I checked /etc/hosts and didn't find anything wrong. However other sites like google.com did resolve.

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67431196/6740589

Answer (score 7):

`wget` needs to be on `ipv4`.

```
wget -4 -O - https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v${HUGO_VERSION}/${HUGO_
ID}_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
```

Comment: whats this `-4` option ? `wget` dont have any such option ..How this command worked for you?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I know it has been a while, but the answere is that when you use "wget" straight from alpine, it actually is busybox that implements part of wget.

But when you do a "apk add wget" you get an actual wget that also supports things such as -4